# Mysql-PHP, pivoting/cross tab based on variable fields

Tags: php, mysql, variables, pivot, crosstab

Hello Everybody and thank you in advance for your help!

I am trying to create a crosstab type query result based on a returned query.
The first query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT
dc.`name`,
Count(pd.dispositionCodeId) AS NumberOfDispos
FROM
pd

 JOIN ph ON (pd.packetHeaderId = ph.packetHeaderId)
 JOIN sc ON (sc.packetHeaderId = ph.packetHeaderId)
 JOIN dc ON pd.dispositionCodeId = dc.dpcodeId
WHERE (`ph`.`customerId` = 60)
GROUP BY
dc.`name`
```

resulting in:

```
Name NumberofDispos
B      400
NO     245
S      134
V      98
```

-- The `name` that I'm returning are variable depending on the customerId, and also on additional where clauses that appear on other similar queries.

Is there a way to pivot the results of the `name` field as column headings in a second table, which a second query will count the occurances of that particular name showing up in another matched field?

```
        B   NO  S   V 
PackA   250 120 61  22
PackB   100 23  62  37
PackC   50  102 11  39
```

Please keep in mind the column headings are variable based on the results fromt the first query.

As far as I can tell, I would need to make a php array and iterate through the sql results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of query is known as a *pivot* but unfortunately MySQL does not have a pivot function so you will want to replicate it using an aggregate function with a `CASE` statement.

If the values are known ahead of time, then you can hard-code the values into the following:

```
SELECT pd.dispositionCodeId,
  sum(case when dc.`name` = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) B,
  sum(case when dc.`name` = 'NO' then 1 else 0 end) NO,
  sum(case when dc.`name` = 'S' then 1 else 0 end) S,
  sum(case when dc.`name` = 'V' then 1 else 0 end) V
FROM pd
JOIN ph 
  ON pd.packetHeaderId = ph.packetHeaderId
JOIN sc 
  ON sc.packetHeaderId = ph.packetHeaderId
JOIN dc 
  ON pd.dispositionCodeId = dc.dpcodeId
WHERE (`ph`.`customerId` = 60)
GROUP BY pd.dispositionCodeId;
```

But if the values or number of `names` are unknown then you can use a prepared statement which creates a dyanmic sql statement to execute.  The code will look like this:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'sum(case when dc.`name` = ''',
      name,
      ''' then 1 else 0 end) AS ',
      name
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM dc;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT pd.dispositionCodeId, ', @sql, ' 
                   FROM pd
                   JOIN ph 
                     ON pd.packetHeaderId = ph.packetHeaderId
                   JOIN sc 
                     ON sc.packetHeaderId = ph.packetHeaderId
                   JOIN dc 
                     ON pd.dispositionCodeId = dc.dpcodeId 
                   WHERE `ph`.`customerId` = 60
                   GROUP BY pd.dispositionCodeId');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: Thank you Bluefeet, this is close and I run into a similar error when trying a similar solution, not sure why:                PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Not Home,sum(case when disposition_codes.`name` = 'Gated Community' then 1 else ' at line 1

Comment: @alex it is hard to tell from the error message as to what the problem is. Is it possible to create a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) with some sample data and your tables?

Comment: bluefeet, thank you again for your help, please let me know if I fiddled correctly, it was my first time :)

Comment: @alex the fiddle looks good. Here are two versions with the sql -- static version -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b4373/3 -- dynamic version -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b4373/7.  Do these generate the result that you want?

Comment: blufeet, the both look great, thank you. The dynamic version is what I was after however with one small twist :)   The line:                  SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT pd.dispositionCodeId,                           how could I set that left most column to reflect the packetHeadId, and now have the count of the variable headers you just created?   Does that question make sense?

Comment: @alex is this what you mean? -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b4373/18 -- If not then edit your OP with the desired result.

Comment: Is it possible to have the sums on one line, so that each line reflects a new packet header id? Thank you again, I greatly appreciate all your help, I've been trying to solve this for weeks now

Comment: @alex do you want the disposition code included?  If not, then the following might work -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b4373/21

Comment: Bluefeet, it did work, I realized I had cut out some records to make it fit in the fiddle, and then I changed the grouped by to the packet headers. Thank you again. The only catch here is that I'm still getting an error when I run it through Navicat.

Comment: Bluefeet, this is it! I realized I had cut out some records to make it fit in the fiddle, and after fixing, I get the resulting multiple relationships. Thank you again.    http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/4a9fe/3/4      One small challenge though, I can get it to work in the fiddle but not in phpmyadmin. I checked the version and that's not it. Getting the error:    #1054 - Unknown column 's' in 'field list'

Comment: any way to get in contact with you?

Comment: @alex this is a community volunteer forum. As such, it seems to me that it's not appropriate to initiate professional contact *unless invited to do so*.

Comment: @alex I am not able to recreate the issue or load the sql fiddle you provided.  Without seeing your system, it would be very difficult to debug your issue.

Comment: @swasheck, my apologies for breaking forum rules, it's just that this thread was getting long and I had a note pop up to take things to a private conversion but I"m too new to initiate one.

Comment: @alex no worries. now you know. TMYK.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
SELECT 
  pd.dispositionCodeId,
  SUM(CASE WHEN dc.`Name` = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 0) AS B,
  SUM(CASE WHEN dc.`Name` = 'NO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 0) AS NO,
  SUM(CASE WHEN dc.`Name` = 'S' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 0) AS S,
  SUM(CASE WHEN dc.`Name` = 'V' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 0) AS V
FROM pd
JOIN ph ON (pd.packetHeaderId = ph.packetHeaderId)
JOIN sc ON (sc.packetHeaderId = ph.packetHeaderId)
JOIN dc ON pd.dispositionCodeId = dc.dpcodeId
WHERE (`ph`.`customerId` = 60)
GROUP BY pd.dispositionCodeId
```

Comment: Thank you PinnyM, although this works, I need it for a dynamic(unknown) column headings.

Comment: Then you'll need to use dynamic SQL - @bluefeet's answer should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If the provided answers are not suitable because you don't know the value of the `name` field before hand and don't want to utilize the prepared statment, you can always just add another level of grouping and perform the "pivot" in your application code.  The select might look like

```
SELECT
dc.`name` as `name`,
dc.`other_field` as `other_field`,
Count(pd.dispositionCodeId) AS NumberOfDispos
FROM
pd
 JOIN ph ON (pd.packetHeaderId = ph.packetHeaderId)
 JOIN sc ON (sc.packetHeaderId = ph.packetHeaderId)
 JOIN dc ON pd.dispositionCodeId = dc.dpcodeId
WHERE (`ph`.`customerId` = 60)
GROUP BY
dc.`name`,
dc.`other_field`
ORDER BY
dc.`name` ASC,
dc.`other_field` ASC
```

You could then build the two dimensional array needed for the pivot table in PHP like (assuming PDO here but the basic gist is same for iterating through result set with other libraries):

```
$final_array = array();
while($row = $statement->fetchObject()) {
    $final_array[$row->name][$row->other_field] = $row->NumberOfDispos;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mike, I will try this out. I really wanted to solve it in MySql though, before trying to sort it out in PHP. I'll circle back and let you know how this works.

Comment: @alex Obviously having dynamic column headings make this a more complex situation in MySQL. My concern with a MySQL-only solution would be that the query itself could become very complex and slow, while reading the data into a multi-dimensional array in PHP is not really any more difficult than reading into a more typical array of database results.